# Using conditional types in return type of promises

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I'm calling an api from a server that returns an array of data from a mongo db. The schema of this data contains an `ObjectID` that references other models in the database. So there are two schemas, one where the property remains an `ObjectID string` and the other is a `populated` property where the `string` becomes an object. Below is the sample type definition, where `prop1` can either be a `string` or an `object`.

```
type Base = {
    name: string;
    description?: string;
    prop1: string; // ObjectID
}

type Populated = {
    prop1: {
        name: string;
        description: string;
    }
}
```

With this, I made a conditional type that can determine whether the returned data is populated or not. The type is a generic that accepts either `true` or `undefined`. If the generic is `true`, it returns the `Base` type with the `prop1` being the type defined in `Populated`, else it simply returns the `Base` type.

```
type Schema<T extends true | undefined> = T extends true ? Omit<Base, keyof Populated> & Populated : Base
```

Then, a function calls the api with the explicit return type (because api call defaults to `any`). It accepts an optional parameter that determines whether to populate the `ObjectID`s or not.

```
const callApi = async <T extends true | undefined>(populate?: T): Promise<(Schema<typeof populate> & {_id: string})[]> =>  {
    // example only
    return {} as any
}
```

I tried to get the `populated` version of this schema, however the type remains `string | { name: string; description: string; }`

```
const test = async () => {
    const populated = await callApi(true)
    populated.map((data) => data.prop1)
    // data.prop1 is type `string | { name: string; description: string; }`,
    // should only be `{ name: string; description: string; }`
}
```

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwLACgCQA7OAWwgC4oFgAnASzwHMBubHAEwgQGMaxhqB7PAH4yFGvSa4wlPmACMIqrUbYAvtmyhIUAAoyArgBs4wCCyipMk6XLKWc%20IqXKLxzVuy7Ue-PArHLcNSwgjXBoAGUOAAsIQjgAHgAVKAgADxM8FgQoKj1oAB8oPUyIADNaUwA%20cyhktIysnMo8qEEoAHlCamB4%20CQAGigAawgQPlKdfSMTFmqAMkmwQ2NTMj6ICWwOAQooDjgDAwBBMGoaxBA8DigklPSITOzcgqKS8rwqgAowKZXhWoAlGRtNIukh4p9IjE4vFNBBxlAfktphB5ugAPrUFh%20JQqAEAbQAutVkNV0MxKBBgHpKHh0CooIhGXgQKp1FhtnhdiZdqgLlcoJ8AeZqnZObskcsZucAO5wbp7A7HU5C5iSlEsAB0cTAn0%20LGMcGFpKgBuAcE1UhksgBqiAA). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two changes that need to be done:

```
type Schema<T extends true | undefined> = T extends true
  ? Omit<Base, keyof Populated> & Populated
  : Base;

const callApi = async <T extends true | undefined = undefined>(
  populate?: T
): Promise<(Schema<T> & { _id: string })[]> => {
  return {} as any;
};
```

You need to set a default type of `undefined` for the generic type `T`. When you call `callApi` without an argument, the type of `T` can not be inferred and inference falls back to the *constraint* of `T`. Since the constraint is a union of `true | undefined`, the conditional type [distributes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over the union and returns a union of both branches.

You also don't want to pass `typeof populate` to `Schema` since `typeof populate` evaluates to a union of `T | undefined` which is also *distributed* in the conditional type. Pass the generic type `T` instead.

```
const test = async () => {
  const populated1 = await callApi();
  populated1.map((data) => data.prop1);
  //                            ^? prop1: string

  const populated2 = await callApi(true);
  populated2.map((data) => data.prop1);
  //                            ^? prop1: { name: string; description: string; }
};
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigbwFBSgOzgWwgC4oFgAnASxwHMBuLKAEwgQGMqxhKB7HAfhJkqtBtjDkeYAIxCK1ehgC+DDKEhQAClICuAGzjAITKKkzjJMkuey4CxUvNGNsLdp2585IxdhXLVdWgAZTYACwh8OAAeABUoCAAPIxwmBCgKHWgAHygdVIgAM2pjAD5TKHiklLSM8izGfigAeXxKYGj4JAAaKABrCBAeQq1dAyMmcoAyUbB9Q2NGEi6IVTY+Mig2OD09AEEwSgrEEBw2KDiE5IhU9MycvILinGMK-JZnsoAKRjAxhcElQwAEoSJpJG0kNEvqEIlE4tN0FAAPqUJjeBRQJTAgDaAF1yshyjZyBBgDpyDh0EooIhaTgQAx-Bh1jhNkZNqgTmcoF9gaZiYxWZs-nNxsZpMcAO5wdpbHb7Q58sRQUXzCbSAB0UTAXy+TEMcH5ROYhs1Eik0mBKoA9DbbA7HU7nbYAHpNC1WRw+DBCjbAVX-CYAJmlsoD212B0oX3u1t+QeMwe1cF1+sNxvKBuAcHNlittvtLuLJfdqvz1jshAxomYrA4lC4vBwNfoWICGCAA)

Comment: Thank you, the solution worked. Just for reference, can you give examples on when a default type is necessary for the compuler to properly infer the type?

Comment: The type of `T` can not be infered if you don't provide any arguments. If inference fails, the type of `T` falls back to the default type. If there is no default type, it falls back to the constraint. The default type therefore did not help with inference, it just changed the type to which the compiler falls back when inference was not possible.